# Upgrade RVM and now PATH is broken

Tags: homebrew, path, ruby, rvm

My `PATH` no longer includes `/usr/local/bin` even though it is the first line of `/etc/paths`:

```
#/etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

$PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/Users/meltemi/.rvm/bin
```

What changed? Well all was working fine until:

Recently updated RVM from 1.24.8 -> 1.25.13 on an OS X 10.9.1 machine with `rvm get stable`

RVM warned me that there was "old stuff laying around" and to run `rvm cleanup all`, so I did.

Then I upgraded Ruby `rvm upgrade 2.0.0-p353 2.1` migrating gemsets along the way...

**Edit:**

I'm using `zsh`:

```
#~/.zshrc
# Path to your oh-my-zsh configuration.
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh
...
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# load RVM
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 

## from brew info zsh
#Add the following to your zshrc to access the online help:
unalias run-help
autoload run-help
HELPDIR=/usr/local/share/zsh/helpfiles
```

Comment: Are you using bash or zsh or another shell? Have you checked the .profile type files for syntax errors that are preventing /etc/paths from getting sourced? PATH=foo with foo not containing the pre-existing $PATH would be something to watch for.

Comment: I'm using `zsh` and I don't see any obvious errors in `.zshrc` *(see edit above)*

Comment: Good - there are only three places you could have a problem. The system, rvm or oh-my-zsh. My answer might assist in knowing if it's the system or one of the two additions you are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an issue with rvm, but with homebrew:

Since 15th of December 2013 zsh is not longer build with the `--enable-etcdir` flag by default. Therefore `/usr/libexec/path_helper` is no longer used to initialize `$PATH` and all path in `/etc/paths` as well as in `/etc/paths.d` are completely ignored. (I know, I just found out myself and am speechless as well.)

Therefore either run `brew update; brew reinstall zsh --enable-etcdir` or add the following to your `.zshrc`:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

For more information on why this was removed, check this [ticket](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/24538) on github.

Answer (score 0):

I can't guess where your problem lies, but here is how I would troubleshoot it.

1. set aside your .zshrc file `mv ~/.zshrc ~/zshrc`
2. open a new terminal window, switch to bash
3. check path (just to see if it shows any changes)
4. run zsh in verbose mode `zsh -v`

Watch carefully on the /usr/libexec/path_helper output and consider running it by hand to see how your path is being assembled.

Once you have a good path, you can add back part or all of your .zshrc file and re-test.

Comment: did step 1. opening a new terminal window (zsh) and then typing `bash` to switch brought me a world of hurt with missing refs, etc. So tried just a blank `.zshrc` and new zsh terminal and now $PATH is even shorter: "/usr/bin:/bin". Like it's not referencing `etc/paths` at all!?!

Comment: `/usr/libexec/path_helper` appears to be a binary file?!? unreadable. starting to think this problem may be at system level. why isn't `/etc/paths` being sourced?

Comment: Oh - you run it `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s` and it parses the various files and spits out a path formed for bash in this case. See the man page for the options...